# Express Session Management: userid is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

Server (omitted the helping functions as they are not relevant to the question):

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const sessions = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mysql = require('mysql');
require('dotenv').config();

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: "password"
});
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

app.use(express.json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  next();
});
app.use(sessions({
  secret: "secret",
  saveUninitialized:true,
  cookie: { path : '/', maxAge: oneDay },
  resave: false,
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to the server!');
});

//signin function, gets hashed password from database and compares it with user supplied password.
app.post('/compare', async (req, res) => {
  const { password, user } = req.body;

  try {
    const hashDB = await getHash(user);
    const confirm = await confirmHash(password, hashDB);
    //if user supplied password matches DB password, set session info and send session token to client.
    if (confirm) {
      req.session.userid = user;
      res.cookie('sessionID', req.sessionID, { maxAge: oneDay, httpOnly: true });
      res.send({ success: true });
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Confirm failed');
  }
});

//if user session is valid, get session info.
app.get('/protected', (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.session.userid;
  if (userId) {
    res.send(`User ID: ${userId}`);
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
});

const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Client :

```
function signin(username, password) {
  const compareRequestBody = JSON.stringify({ user: username, password });

  const compareRequestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': compareRequestBody.length,
    },
    body: compareRequestBody,
  };

  fetch('http://localhost:8080/compare', compareRequestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data); 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}

function getProfile(){
  const getProfileOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
  }
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/protected', getProfileOptions)
    .then(response=>{
      if (response.ok){
        console.log(response)
      } else {
        console.error('Error: ', response.status)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error: ', error)
  })
}
```

I have a server which upon a successful user log in, will set req.session.userid = user, and send the session token to the client. After I log in, I can see the sessionID in the Set-Cookie header, however when I try to access the /protected endpoint with getProfile(), req.session.userid is undefined.